# Can an upgraded 2012 Build Template be used with older TFS server

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

I have upgraded my project that hast the Build Template to use 2012 (11.00 assemblies) and upgraded it to use .NET framework 4.5. I have also upgraded the Custom Activities project to use version 4.5 framework and use 11.00 assemblies.

I have several questions regarding this can i use this upgraded template with TFS 2010? At the moment our server which has TFS 2010 installed hasn't been upgraded to TFS 2012.

Also the custom activities that I use in the upgraded template, they look grey. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

Custom Activities should match with the version of Team Foundation Build Services. As you are using TFS 2010 build services, it will throw errors for the custom activities compiled with 11.0 version.